# lwc createrecord not working it is setting up wrong value

Tags: lightning-web-components

we have inputcheck box to read a value form user interface.

Though user did not click on the checkbox it is setting up wrong value i.e. True. Also by Default value for this checkbox is False. and we are not performing any insert or update operation on this object it is brand new object. we are only inserting this object through LWC 'lightning/uiRecordApi'

Pleased find the LWC code:

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" name="Include SA Stone Form ADV - Part 2A" label="Include SA Stone Form ADV - Part 2A" onclick={handleADVChange} data-id="ADVPart2">
</lightning-input> 

import { createRecord, updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ADV_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Notes__c.Form_ADV_Part_2A_Sent_On__c'; 

@track ADVvalue = false;

handleADVChange(event){
    this.ADVvalue =event.target.value;
     // this.ADVvalue =event.detail.value;
}

 createNote() {
fields[SUBJECT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.subject;
fields[ADV_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.ADVvalue;
console.log('======fields[ADV_FIELD.fieldApiName]==='+fields[ADV_FIELD.fieldApiName]);  // getting correct boolean value i.e False value

 const recordInput = { apiName: NOTES_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };

 console.log('====recordInput==='+JSON.stringify(recordInput));  // here also getting correct value in JSON 

createRecord(recordInput)
.then(notes => {
          console.log('====notes==='+JSON.stringify(notes));   // getting wrong value, it is making boolean value true.(By default value for boolean variable is False) 
   })
   .catch(error => {

        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error creating record',
                message: error.body.message,
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );
    });     
    
 }
```

It will be great if someone can help us on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There could be few reason for that.

1- There is some trigger on your NOTES_OBJECT which is changing that field value to true on insertion of record.

2-Or there can be any process builder/flow that is making this value to true.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response. 

That possibility I checked, but it is newly created object. Yesterday only it has created and it dont have any trigger or flow and anything else.

Comment: Hope you are not passing "False" as a string.  Just pass 'key':false

Comment: This is, again (and IMHO), something that should be presented as a comment against the original question rather than as an answer since it is purely speculative.

Comment: No not passing it as a string.. passing value as a true. 

Form_ADV_Part_2A_Sent_On__c":{
"displayValue":null,
"value":true
}